# Write each row of a spark dataframe as a separate file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, file-writing

I have Spark Dataframe with a single column, where each row is a long string (actually an xml file).
I want to go through the DataFrame and save a string from each row as a text file, they can be called simply 1.xml, 2.xml, and so on.

I cannot seem to find any information or examples on how to do this.
And I am just starting to work with Spark and PySpark.
Maybe map a function on the DataFrame, but the function will have to write string to text file, I can't find how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When saving a dataframe with Spark, one file will be created for each partition. Hence, one way to get a single row per file would be to first repartition the data to as many partitions as you have rows.

There is a library on [github](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) for reading and writing XML files with Spark. However, the dataframe needs to have a special format to produce correct XML. In this case, since you have everything as a string in a single column, the easiest way to save would probably be as csv.

The repartition and saving can be done as follows:

```
rows = df.count()
df.repartition(rows).write.csv('save-dir')
```

Comment: Does the count method need to read all the data first bring in memory as dataframe and then repartition and write it? What if input size is to large ? Will count method is imposing all the data must be read first.

Comment: Not sure if it reads *all* data in memory but it does quite some processing to get the count yes

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way in Java and Hadoop FileSystem API. You can write similar code using Python.

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("file1", "file2", "file3");
JavaRDD<String> stringrdd = new JavaSparkContext().parallelize(strings);
stringrdd.collect().foreach(x -> {
    Path outputPath = new Path(x);
    Configuration conf = getConf();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    OutputStream os = fs.create(outputPath);
});
```

Comment: I don't know java, so I will use the next solution. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Where does getConf() come from?

Comment: Do you have to connect the dataframe first before this solution can work?

Comment: Calling `collect()` on the `RDD` would pull all of it into memory on the driver - which may or may not work, depending on the size of your data.