# jupyter: using a dataframe created in another notebook

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

I'm using jupyter notebooks to manipulate some date;

I want to know in jupyter, if it is possible to use a dataframe df1 created in the notebook n1.ipynb in another notebook n2.ipynb without recreating it?

Comment: With Pandas dataframes, you can easily pickle  (serialize) them; however, that doesn't look to be the case with pyspark, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70355345/8508004). That answer proposes a solution & maybe you can try it. Otherwise it looks like you save it as a CSV file (or maybe as JSON data?) from the one notebook & read it back in for the other. Maybe looking at more similar questions & solutions will help? I noted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60316076/8508004) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57437643/8508004) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47250715/8508004).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will look it up, i'll try those solutions and comeback to you if it works