# How to save each row of a DataFrame as a HDFS file using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a file that is ctrl A delimited and has the following header:

filename','file_metadata','data_content','status','errortype','error_message'

I need to dump individual files to hdfs for each record of the file to directories like - basepath_errortype_filename/file.json , and the content of the file would be the data_content column.

Showing the sample data:

```
>>> ff_df = ff_rdd.toDF(['file_name','file_metadata','data_content','status','error_type','error_message'])
>>> ff_df .show()
+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------+-------------+--------------------+
|     file_name|file_metadata|        data_content|status|   error_type|       error_message|
+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------+-------------+--------------------+
|test_file.json|     metadata|{ "fruit": "Apple...|FAILED| INVALID_JSON|     could not parse|
|demo_file.json|     metadata|{ "fruit": "Apple...|FAILED|MISSING_RULES|No matching rules...|
+--------------+-------------+--------------------+------+-------------+--------------------+
```

Now I need these two rows as two files in hdfs, in folders /tmp/INVALID_JSON_test_file and /tmp/MISSING_RULES_demo_file . I have written the following pyspark code , but I am not getting the desired result. Please help

````
def write_file(line)
 tokens=line.split("\x01")
 file_name=tokens[0]
 error_type=tokens[4]
 content=tokens[2]
 #define path to saved file
 file_name = %s + "/" + 
 directory_name = basePath"/"error_type"/"file_name
 return directory_name

# get the file content
ff_rdd = sc.textFile("/tmp/pyspark1.txt").map(lambda line: line.split("\x01"))
ff_df = ff_rdd.toDF(['file_name','file_metadata','data_content','status','error_type','error_message'])
content_df = ff_df.select("data_content")

file_path = sc.textFile("/tmp/pyspark1.txt").map(lambda line: write_file(line))
content_df.rdd.saveAsTextFile("file_path")```
````

Answer (score 0):

Sample Input:

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------+-------------+-----------------+
|     file_name|file_metadata|       data_content|status|   error_type|    error_message|
+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------+-------------+-----------------+
|test_file.json|     metadata|{ "fruit": "Apple"}|FAILED| INVALID_JSON|  could not parse|
|demo_file.json|     metadata|   { "fruit": "Ab"}|FAILED|MISSING_RULES|No matching rules|
+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------+-------------+-----------------+
```

First, we will concatenate `error_type` column and `file_name` column (only the file name, excluding the extension) to create `newColumn`.

```
final_df = df_new.withColumn("newColumn",concat(col("error_type"),lit("_"),split("file_name","\.")[0]))
```

On running `df_new.show(truncate=false)` we will see the sample output as :

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
|file_name     |file_metadata|data_content       |status|error_type   |error_message    |newColumn              |
+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
|test_file.json|metadata     |{ "fruit": "Apple"}|FAILED|INVALID_JSON |could not parse  |INVALID_JSON_test_file |
|demo_file.json|metadata     |{ "fruit": "Ab"}   |FAILED|MISSING_RULES|No matching rules|MISSING_RULES_demo_file|
+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
```

To achieve the directory structure in the required format ex: Base_directory/INVALID_JSON_test_file ,while writing we will have to partition the final_df on the basis of the `newColumn` created.

We can write using the following :

```
final_df.select("data_content","newColumn").write.partitionBy("newColumn").save(FilePath)
```

By default a parquet file will be written.
I don't think it will be possible to write the output as a text file as it doesn't accept multiple columns, we will require the `newColumn` to be written along with the `data_content` because we are partitioning the dataframe on the basis of `newColumn`.

Comment: Thank you so much @RohanGupta . Since I absolutely have to write the file as a text file , I was thinking of taking an RDD approach here:  basePath="/tmp/test/"
def write_file(line):
 tokens=line.split("\x01")
 file_name=tokens[0]
 error_type=tokens[4]
 content=tokens[2]
 directory_name = basePath+"/"+error_type+"/"+file_name
 content.saveAsTextFile("directory_name")
 return directory_name
 
file_rdd = sc.textFile("/tmp/pyspark1.txt")
file_rdd.foreach(write_file)  But it is erroring out with error - AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile' . Can you help ?

Comment: @Kuwali check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883129/write-each-row-of-a-spark-dataframe-as-a-separate-file